# How do i fix my application for a roku tv

Tags: xml, brightscript

The Error is

> Install Failure: Compilation Failed.HelloWorld
> if you can help download
> `https://dev-fonoxy.pantheonsite.io/stackoverflow/ClockSaver.zip`
> for fixes upload to
> `https://dev-fonoxy.pantheonsite.io/stackoverflow/filemgr.php`
> I have tried everything on chat gpt but it did not work i tried github did not work so pleas can you help me
> hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems with your app.

1. you're referencing `HelloWorld.brs` from `pkg:/source`, but the correct path is `pkg:/components/helloworld.brs`.
   [image]
2. You shouldn't call the `init` function yourself. This is something the Roku platform will call for you whenever a new instance of your `HelloWorld` component is initialized. Also...it's invalid syntax to run top-level code like this. Code statements are only valid inside function bodies.
   [image]
3. `LabelNode` is not a valid component type. Did you mean `Label`?
   [image]

Here's a screenshot after I fixed these 3 problems:
[image]

I highly recommend installing Visual Studio Code (VSCode) and the [BrightScript Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RokuCommunity.brightscript) extension for VSCode. Many of these types of errors will be flagged during development time.

Comment: [https://dev-fonoxy.pantheonsite.io/stackoverflow/UpdatedClockSaver.zip the image now wont show up when i load it as a screensaver can any one help

Comment: If i've answered your first question, can you please mark it as the answer? This also seems like a completely new question and doesn't belong in the current question. For future questions, it would be best for you to paste code snippets instead of links to zips. Here's an explanation of how to ask good questions on StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask